# PLSQL syntax error near ";"

Tags: sql, plsql, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to run a query for liquibase update and I have a PLSQL block in there, the block has over 500 lines so I only post a few lines where the error is happening for now.

```
      BEGIN     
            IF NOT EXISTS(select 1 from "public"."eod_report" where "id" = NEW."id") THEN
            -- LOADING STRUCTURE  SECTION
            select "id" into NEW.organization_unit_id from organization_unit where site_id = NEW.organization_unit_id;
                orgUnitId := CAST(NEW.organization_unit_id as int8);
                --INSERT
                IF (NEW.transactions_count is NULL) THEN
                NEW.transactions_count := 0;
                END IF;
                IF (NEW.total_sales is NULL) THEN
                NEW.total_sales := 0; 
                END IF;
            INSERT INTO "public"."eod_report"("id",batch,total_sales,transactions_count,organization_unit_id,pos_total_sales,pos_transactions_count,pos_total_points,total_points,transaction_date) 
            VALUES (NEW."id",NEW.batch,NEW.total_sales,NEW.transactions_count,orgUnitId,NEW.pos_total_sales,NEW.pos_transactions_count,NEW.pos_total_points,NEW.total_points,NEW.transaction_date);  
            -- updates delay transaction or each batch
                select max(id) into lastEodId from "public"."transaction"  where transaction_type = 4 and org_unit_id = orgUnitId and id &lt ;NEW."id"; 
            for eodRow IN       
            select count(case when transaction_type = 3 then -1 else 1 end) as trCount,sum(case when report_prefix = true then points else -points end) as ptSum,sum(case when report_prefix = true then amount else -amount end) as trSum, batch as trBatch from "public"."transaction"
              where id &gt ;lastEodId and id &lt ;NEW."id" and report_prefix is not null and org_unit_id = orgUnitId
              and batch &lt ;NEW.batch group by batch

            LOOP 
              UPDATE "public"."eod_report" SET delayed_points = 
          (delayed_points + eodRow.ptSum),former_delayed_sales =  
            END LOOP;
            END IF;


            RETURN NULL;
```

And I am getting this error when I try to execute the query:

ERROR:

> syntax error at or near ";"
>   LINE 453: ..._type = 4 and org_unit_id = orgUnitId and id &lt ;NEW."id"; 
>                                                                             ^
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 15018

[there is a screenshot where the error is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Nu2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `<` and `>` chars are replaced with `&lt ;` so the syntax is incorrect.

fix the SQL by replacing all  `&lt ;` with `<` to have

```
... org_unit_id = orgUnitId and id < NEW."id";
```

Also `&gt ;` must be replaced with `>`

It could happens e.g. because of URL encoding of text sent from UI (browser)

Comment: I'm surprised it works because PL/SQL has no `"IF NOT EXISTS(select"` construction, despite people routinely assuming that it should.

Answer (score 0):

You find the same problem in multiple parts of your query, because HTML entities like "&lt ;" and "&gt ;" are not legal in an SQL query, which the error points to. You should change them to "<" and ">" accordingly.